# Strange array repitition behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Hi this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I am writing a table building class for an application.

i start by configuring the table using this code below.

```
$table->setPage('page.rows','20');
$table->setPage('page.start','0');

$table->setTable('table.name','customertable');
$table->setTable('table.higlight','true');

$table->setColumn('column.name','id');                          
$table->setColumn('column.key','index');                        
$table->setColumn('column.heading','none');                     
$table->setColumn('column.issort','false');                     
$table->setColumn('column.islink','false');                     
$table->setColumn('column.ischeck','true');                     
$table->insertColumn();                                         

$table->setColumn('column.name','jobref');                                          
$table->setColumn('column.key','job-ref');                      
$table->setColumn('column.heading','RB Ref');                       
$table->setColumn('column.issort','true');                      
$table->setColumn('column.islink','true');                      
$table->setColumn('column.ischeck','false');                
$table->insertColumn();

$table->setColumn('column.name','type');                                            
$table->setColumn('column.key','type');                     
$table->setColumn('column.heading','Job Type');                     
$table->setColumn('column.issort','true');                      
$table->setColumn('column.islink','true');                      
$table->setColumn('column.ischeck','false');                
$table->insertColumn();
```

its not important what the values are apart from the setColumn method adds the values to a temporary array via the function call below.

```
public function setColumn($key,$value){
    $this->colParamSet[$key] = $value;      
    }
```

then when i have finished with my param list i use

```
$table->insertColumn();
```

which calls this code below

```
public function insertColumn(){
    
    $this->columnConfig[$this->colParamSet['column.name']] = $this->colParamSet;        
        
    print_r($this->columnConfig); #this is for test purposes not part of the final code
    
    }
```

I hope i have explained everything ok so far Now....here is the output

```
Array ( 

[id] => Array ( [column.name] => id [column.key] => index [column.heading] => none [column.issort] => false [column.islink] => false [column.ischeck] => true ) 

) 

Array ( 

[id] => Array ( [column.name] => id [column.key] => index [column.heading] => none     [column.issort] => false [column.islink] => false [column.ischeck] => true ) 
[jobref] => Array ( [column.name] => jobref [column.key] => job-ref [column.heading] => RB Ref [column.issort] => true [column.islink] => true [column.ischeck] => false ) 

) 

Array ( 

[id] => Array ( [column.name] => id [column.key] => index [column.heading] => none [column.issort] => false [column.islink] => false [column.ischeck] => true ) 
[jobref] => Array ( [column.name] => jobref [column.key] => job-ref [column.heading] => RB Ref [column.issort] => true [column.islink] => true [column.ischeck] => false ) 
[type] => Array ( [column.name] => type [column.key] => type [column.heading] => Job Type [column.issort] => true [column.islink] => true [column.ischeck] => false ) 

)
```

each config set is the settings for each column within the table also the key that points to the array is the db coloumn name that is used to pull the data from a assoc array that contains the data for the table.

I don't understand why i am getting this repetition of arrays. the only way i have got this to work is using the code below

```
public function insertColumn(){
    $this->columnConfig = array();
    $this->columnConfig[$this->colParamSet['column.name']] = $this->colParamSet;        
    $this->colParamSet = array();
    
    
    print_r($this->columnConfig);
    
    }
```

this works OK and outputs what i need but i cant for the life of me understand why it does work because it seems as if i am clearing the arrays entirely then inserting one cell with an array and then clearing it again but its not behaving that way and because i don't understand it i cant rely on it as i may have created an unstable hack that's gonna throw a wobble in production.

I hope i have made this question understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry I forgot to show the output i was trying to acheive so here it is below

```
Array ( 

[id] => Array ( [column.name] => id [column.key] => index [column.heading] => none         [column.issort] => false [column.islink] => false [column.ischeck] => true ) 
[jobref] => Array ( [column.name] => jobref [column.key] => job-ref [column.heading] =>     RB Ref [column.issort] => true [column.islink] => true [column.ischeck] => false ) 
[type] => Array ( [column.name] => type [column.key] => type [column.heading] => Job Type [column.issort] => true [column.islink] => true [column.ischeck] => false ) 

)
```

---

### **Code for Comparison**

I hope i dont get into trouble for making this question too big but i have produce the code below for comparison

```
$temp = array(); 
$final = array(); 

function setconfig($key,$value){ 
    global $temp;     
    $temp[$key] = $value; 
    } 

function insertarray(){ 
    global $final, $temp; 
    $final[$temp['config.name']] = $temp; 
    } 

setconfig('config.name','bob'); 
setconfig('config.width','50'); 
setconfig('config.height','50'); 
setconfig('config.class','bobs-box'); 
insertarray(); 

setconfig('config.name','jon'); 
setconfig('config.width','150'); 
setconfig('config.height','150'); 
setconfig('config.class','jons-box'); 
insertarray(); 

setconfig('config.name','sue'); 
setconfig('config.width','150'); 
setconfig('config.height','150'); 
setconfig('config.class','sues-box'); 
insertarray(); 

print_r($final);
```

the output IS the desired output below

```
Array ( 

[bob] => Array ( [config.name] => bob [config.width] => 50 [config.height] => 50 [config.class] => bobs-box ) 
[jon] => Array ( [config.name] => jon [config.width] => 150 [config.height] => 150 [config.class] => jons-box ) 
[sue] => Array ( [config.name] => sue [config.width] => 150 [config.height] => 150 [config.class] => sues-box ) 
)
```

so can anyone tell me the difference between the array being within an object and why its not behaving the same way? or should i just forget about it and use the fix and move on.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Nicely done for your first question :)

Comment: I have added the desired output to the Q. Thanks Ray

Comment: I may post this again simplified.

Answer (score 1):

You have one object `$table`.

`$this->columnConfig` is a property of that object.

Each time you call the `insertColumn()` method it uses the same `columnConfig` it used before.

When you add the line `$this->columnConfig = array();` , you kind of "reset" that property.

Hope you understood.

Comment: OK Thanks so if i have reset the columnConfig array wouldn't it be empty? so the output would only be the very last configset i insert. That is whats confusing me because i don't understand where the array is being stored after it has been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

sorry every body i have answered my question. When the penny dropped i realised what a numbmty i have been.

I was printing the array out during the build iteration of the array hence the values seemingly repeating themselves but not. DOH!! should learn to leave alone on the weekend when the kids are home. Great way to introduce myself i spose HAHA